# Error de E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle-sqldeveloper

Ya he reiniciado servicios he visto que estén correctamente en el `listener.ora` pero aún me marca como si no lo detecta.

Me sigue saliendo esto

> Se ha producido un error al realizar la operación solicitada:
>
> Error de E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
>
> Código de proveedor 17002

Este seria mi listener.ora

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\nuevacarpeta\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.    

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
      (SID_LIST =
        (SID_DESC =
          (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
          (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\nuevacarpeta\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
          (PROGRAM = extproc)
          (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:D:\app\nuevacarpeta\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
        )
      )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

A mi me salio el mismo error, cuando le cambie el nombre a mi pc. Lo solucione modificando los archivos *listener.ora*, *tnsnames.ora*. Ademas ejecute en el cmd `lsnrctl status` y `lsnrctl start` y listo. Yo me guie de aqui https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWdODgQwE6k
Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Es probable que esté mal el hostname. Ejecutando `lsnrctl status` en el cmd (como administrador) podrás ver el hosntname actual. Eso lo modificas en el *listener.ora* y/o en el *tnsnames.ora* (Creo que en el 21c solo está en el *listener.ora*). Guardas cambios y estableces la conexión.